# Как выглядит возвращаемая ссылка на объект с++

Tags: c++, ооп

1) Я не понимаю как выглядит *this

2) Я не понимаю как выглядит возваращаемая ссылка на объект

3)Когда вовращается эта ссылка то что происходит в части c=a=b

```
 MyClass& operator = (const MyClass& copyObject) {
        //Копирую динамический массив
        return *this 
    }

    int main(){
    MyClass a(5);
    MyClass b(3)
    MyClass c(3)
    c=a=b;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)*this равносильна любой другой переменной(только означает что в данном случает речь идет об объекте внутри которой используется эта this,т.е. "этот объект", т.е. MyClass), объекту, то есть, просто копия. 
Например int a. C таким же успехом вы бы могли просто вместо *this написать MyClass.

2)Возвращаемая ссылка выглядит как обычная ссылка то есть int &ref=переменная,т.е. мы возвращаем ссылку а не копию.

3) с получает значение a , а получает значение b. По ссылке.

Простой пример:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        a = 5;
    }
    SomeClass(int l_a)
    {
        a = l_a;
    }

    SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass &l_copy)
    {
        this->a = l_copy.a;
        return *this;
    }

    int a;
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass a;
    SomeClass b(1);
    b = a;
    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;



}
```

Comment: 1) this //Получаю адрес объекта b. |    *this //Сам объект b ???? 2)Куда я эту ссылку присваиваю или записываю ну или куда возвращаю?

Comment: Если происходит такая запись то как с нею взаимодействует объект c ? Это будет так : MyClass &b = b .  А потом c = &b ?

Comment: Господи , сколько уже времени сижу - ничего не понимаю.Я пробую понять как все прям шаг за шагом происходит

Comment: Я не понимаю как они ПО ССЫЛКЕ получают значения

Comment: С this да вы все правильно понимаете. С ссылками все точно так же как допустим int &ref; int a= ref. В вашем примере будет так: MyClass& ref=b; a=ref; и все и т.д.

Comment: Я возможно понял. Когда я передаю параметр то const MyClass& copyObject = b; Дальше я возвращаю объект b (*this) , но так как я указываю что у меня вот такой тип возвращаемых данных  MyClass& то я должен взять ссылку объекта b , то есть copyObject . И тогда a = copyObject

Comment: Нельзя но это просто пример. У вас оператор присваивания вроде неправильно определен.

Comment: Пример верный и рабочий , что не скажешь про мою голову

Comment: Покажите весь код.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084043/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-return-this

Comment: Нет. Вы не правильно понимаете. return *this это не объект B а A. Просто создается отдельная ссылка на MyClass(вы ее не видите) которой передается значение A.

Comment: Я вот никак не пойму как по этой ссылке передается мой объект А (я к стати не заметил что оговорился , я имел в виду что *this это A).Куда он передается?

Comment: Передается самой себе. Знайте что выражение a=b означает что значение b передается а по ссылке а не по значению. Оператор = работает только с двумя объектами.  О c можете забыть. Думайте так : a =b , c =a;

Comment: В общем что я понимаю : *this  это мой текущий объект. Я его куда-то передаю(наверное вместо с=(a=b) будет просто с=a ) через ссылку на MyClass. Как создается эта ссылка?Можна пример с MyClass?

Comment: Я вам показывал пример. Читайте выше.Просто в классах такая имплементация (на самом деле имееться ввиду ссылка объекта в аргументе) .  А вообще возьмите пример попроще. Код в ответе.